# filter function in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Current i have Implement in the filter function in the array and here is the program.

```
 <HTML>
                       <div *ngFor="let cinemadatas of cinoperator">
                                <a class="dashboard-stat dashboard-stat-v2 white button-cathay" (click)="getOperatorId(cinemadatas._id)" href="javascript:void(0)">

                                    <div class="desc uppercase">
                                                <strong>{{ cinemadatas.cinema_operator_name }}</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </a>
    <-----------------------------list of items------------------------------>   


    <tr class="cinema-row cathay" *ngFor="let cintable of filteredCinema">
                                                  <td>
                                                      <a href="/venues/cinemas/1" class="uppercase">{{cintable.cinema_name}}</a>
                                                      <span class="label label-sm label-warning label-mini">{{cintable.status}}</span>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <img src="/img/logo-cinema-operator-cathay.jpg" height="30">
                                                      {{cintable.cinema_operator_id}}
                                                  </td>
     <-------------------------com.ts-------------------------------->
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CinemaService } from './cinemas.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cinemas',
  templateUrl: './cinemas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cinemas.component.css'],
  providers: [CinemaService]
})
export class CinemasComponent implements OnInit {

  cinoperator = [];
  filteredCinema = [];


  constructor(private cinemaService: CinemaService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.cinema();
    this.master();

  }

 master() {
    this.cinemaService.getCinMaster()
      .subscribe(
      (response: any) => { this.filteredCinema = response; },
      (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

 cinema() {
    this.cinemaService.getCinMaster()
      .subscribe(
      (response: any) => { this.cinoperator = response; },
      (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }


  getOperatorId(id: string) {
    console.log(id);
    this.filteredCinema = this.cinMaster.filter(function (e) {
      if (e.cinema_operator_id === id) {
        return e;
      }
      //return this.cinMaster;      
    });

  }
  }
```

the filter function is working if we select one option (cinemadatas.cinema_operator_name) it will get filter but when we select the next option it will filter but previous selected will not effect in the list. Please help me with this issue.

cinoperator = []; filteredCinema = []; both contain unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, always present your code as such that it's readable ;)

But off to question. You should store the values you want to filter by in an array, for example `stpreFilters`. Then push or remove the id's based on selection, then filter your array. So something like...

```ts
storeFilters = []

getOperatorId(id: string) {
  if (this.storeFilters.indexOf(id) == -1) {
    this.storeFilters.push(id)
  } else {
    this.storeFilters.splice(this.storeFilters.indexOf(id), 1)
  }
  this.filteredCinema = this.cinMaster.filter(x => this.storeFilters.indexOf(x.id) != -1)
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwcu7j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**